# Error connecting to mac from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, pairing, remote-login

[image]I have the right IP address although when I go to connect to my mac I get this error message:

`An error occurred while generating the SSH keys. Please check that the environment is properly configured. Details: cat: /Users/cbcb/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Keys/---------------------: No such file or directory`

I have tried creating a new admin user, I have remote login enabled, and when I go to the following location above the folder is blanked.

[image]

Comment: **First** ,if `IP` exists in list , right click to [Forget this Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyXGl.png) . **Second** , you'd better reboot Mac. **Third**, click [Add Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oIY2.png) to type the `IP` to check whehter can connect .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed this problem by manually importing the public ssh key in MonoTouch folder into the authorized_keys on mac.
To do so :
1- Copy the content of 'id_rsa.pub' located in "%localAppData%/Xamarin/Monotouch"
2- In your MAC (assuming that it is running on a VM), go to "/Users//.ssh/Authorized_keys" Open the file, paste the key in a new line, save then close.
3- Now go back to your Visual Studio and try again, you'll be able to pair your macOS
Enjoy

Comment: I forgot your email and I ran into another issue: Couldn't connect to 192.168.1.15. Please try again.
The Broker initialization exceeded the timeout of 60000 millisecs without receiving confirmation from the Broker. Any ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: Did u reinstall the macOS?

Comment: yes, this time I did not have to do those steps you told me though. But I am still getting that error message

Comment: Sorry this one is new to me and even in the internet there is no concluding solution. What I can say for now is, you may program your application directly on macOS, or you can share the code between your macOS and windows, so you can program on windows then test the ios version on mac. Anyhow, I can help you with teamviewer doing a proper setup to your virtual machine.

Comment: whats a teamviewer would you be able to make another chatroom

Comment: The value from my id_rsa.pub was already in the authorized_keys file on the MAC for me. Still broken. Not a fix, at least for all.

Comment: @coder123 i am having the same issue. very frustrating. did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch
3. Start Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

If you try and delete the directory:
`Delete C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoTouch`

When you relaunch visual studio and it prompts for your Apple login info you need to use the login information for the user who is currently logged in on the Mac.  If you use a different account then the current user it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may need to redirect that to your default `.ssh` key location. Mine on my Mac is `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Also blank out your SSH keys please, just for security.

Comment: how would I do this