# An error occurred while generating the SSH keys. Please check that the environment is properly configured

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019, pairing

Whenever I try to connect to my mac using visual studio 2019 I get this error message:

`An error occurred while generating the SSH keys. Please check that the environment is properly configured. Details: cat: /Users/cc/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/Keys/636689b9-d636-49b2-b0e4-5ef733a64faa: No such file or directory`

When I go to this place on my mac It's empty. If anyone has any ideas for how to fix this please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error connecting to mac from visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310365/error-connecting-to-mac-from-visual-studio)

Comment: please do not post the same question mulitple times

Comment: @Jason No one has answered it though and I am really desperate for an answer.

Comment: First, someone did answer.  Second, not getting an answer is NOT a reason to post a duplicate, per SO guidelines.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Update your Visual Studio, this error gets fixed with the latest update..