# Pair to Mac: An error occurred while executing an SSH command. Error code: 134

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

After updating MacOS, XCode, Visual Studio Mac and Visual Studio Windows,  I get the error

```
An error occurred while trying to connect to the Broker...
An error occurred while executing an SSH command. Error code: 134
```

[image]

Comment: Do you see this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310365/error-connecting-to-mac-from-visual-studio

Answer (score 1):

I was logged into my Mac under a different account than I used to connect from Visual Studio.

You might get the same issue if you are not logged into the Mac.